# Conditionals and Implications

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

Until recently, I wasn't aware of the subtle difference in $\to$ and $\implies$. I've read the previous answers, and want to put it all together to corroborate my understanding.

$P \to Q$ is a propositional statement formed by the binary logical connective $\to$ and two statements $P,Q.$ I see $P \to Q$ as a promise, thereby motivating its truth table where it's only false when $P$ is true and $Q$ is false.

Say, we are proving the theorem $$n\text{ is even}\implies n=2m\text{ for some integer }m.$$ Now, when we write at the end of our proof that $P \implies Q$, what we are saying is that if $P$ holds, then $Q$ also holds, if truth value of $P$ is 1, then truth value of $Q$ is also 1. That is, through our proof, we are denying there being any case of $P$ true and $Q$ false. So if I am to relate $P \implies Q$ to $P \to Q$, I'd say that $P \implies Q$ asserts that it cannot be the case that $P$ holds and $Q$ doesn't hold, thereby ultimately saying that $P \to Q$ is always true (including trivial vacuous cases), i.e. $P \to Q$ is a tautology.

$P \iff Q$ asserts if $P$ holds, then $Q$ also holds; and if $Q$ holds, then $P$ also holds. In relation to $P \leftrightarrow Q$, it says that $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is a tautology, i.e. $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is always true, thereby saying that the truth values of $P$ and $Q$ always go together as the same; and that it cannot be the case that truth values of $P$ and $Q$ are different. $P \iff Q$ is also called logical equivalence.

I've read that $\implies$ and $\iff$ are not connectives, but that they are making meta statements (statements about about propositions $P$ and $Q$). Are $\implies$ and $\iff$ just shorthand then for saying, "if you start with $P$, you can deduce $Q$" and "if you start with $Q$, you can deduce $P$" etc. ?

Comment: Mostly.   It is much preferred to use $\to$ as the logical connective within a conditional statement, to distinguish it from the use of $\!\implies\!$ as logical entailment between statements, but many texts do still use $\!\implies\!$ for both purposes.

Comment: It is possible to derive $(A\implies B)\iff \neg (A\land \neg B)$ from "first principles." Here is my formal proof using a form of natural deduction: http://www.dcproof.com/DeriveImplies.html (requires some knowledge of the basic methods of proof). I make no distinction between the different kinds of implication that you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **when we write at the end of our proof** that $P{\implies}Q,$ we are asserting that it cannot be the case that $P$ holds and $Q$ doesn't hold,

Yes.

> thereby ultimately saying that $P \to Q$ is *always* true, i.e. $P \to Q$ is a **tautology**.

No; based on your described context, $(P{\implies}Q)$ likely means that the conditional $(P \to Q)$ is universally true under the assumption of mathematical axioms/definitions, that is, that something like $$\forall x \;\forall y \;\Big(P(x,y) \to Q(x,y)\Big)\tag1$$ is mathematically true. Here, $(P \to Q)$ is **not** generally a tautology, and, typically, statement $(1)$ is not a [logical validity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3884853/21813).

In the context of your above sentence, the word *always* (equivalently: *necessarily*) is not well-scoped (and actually redundant), and tripping you up: **in the current theory,** $(P \to Q)$ is (always) true and $Q$ is (always) true whenever $P$ is true.

In short: mathematical truths are generally not tautologies.

> $P{\iff}Q$ asserts that $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is a **tautology**, i.e. $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is *always* true. $P{\iff}Q$ is also called logical equivalence.

Similarly, based on your described context, $(P{\iff}Q)$ asserts that $P$ and $Q$ are mathematically equivalent, but asserts neither that they are logically nor that they are tautologically equivalent.

> Are $\implies$ and $\iff$ just shorthand for saying, "if you start with $P$, you can deduce $Q$" and "if you start with $Q$, you can deduce $P$" etc. ?

Based on your described context, yes (assuming mathematical definitions and results).

> I've read that $\implies$ and $\iff$ are not connectives, but that they are making meta statements.

Based on your described context, these two symbols are connectives but not material connectives.

> I wasn't aware of the subtle difference in $\to$ and $\implies$.

The following answers that I wrote elaborate on this answer:

1. [material conditional and implication](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3884866/21813)
2. [material conditional, implication, logical implication](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4251001/21813)
3. [material biconditional, universal equivalence, equivalence, logical equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4465471/21813)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138282/discussion-on-answer-by-ryang-conditionals-and-implications).